# What is the difference between "myself vs i myself do."?

Tags: grammar, pronouns

Sometimes ago, I was facing with native speakers he used " Myself & I Myself Do." could you help me out about importance of this sentence "I will eat myself." & "I myself will eat."

Comment: Please don't say *"I will eat myself"* - it means you eat your won body parts (i.e., flesh, skin, fingers)

Comment: @AIQ I'm not sure that's the only way to interpret it.

Comment: @userr2684291 Oh yes, you are right. Perhaps one can say that when someone else is trying to feed them. Is that what you mean? Or perhaps they want to eat alone without any company?

Comment: @AIQ I imagined it as a way of saying *I'll eat, too*, with an emphasis on *I*. It's similar to the second example. *Well, I'll be eating myself, so we might as well do it together*.

Comment: @userr2684291 Yes that makes sense. I hadn't thought of putting that part in context. I just assumed (wrongly) that OP's sentence with a period is all that they are trying to say, and for some reason, cannibalism came to mind.

Comment: what is the difference between "Myself & Mine."

Answer (score 1):

The 'myself' can serve a few purposes here.

1. As per the other answers, it emphasises the 'I',
2. As per the other answers, 'I will do it myself' i.e. I don't need your help.
3. It also serves to contrast that 'I' will be doing something that you/others may or may not be doing. For example

`I myself will eat, while you continue to play video games and let your food get cold.`

Hope this helps.